# Can I open multiple tabs with a single button in Wicket 9.6?

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have a ListMultipleChoice object that I'm using on my homePage. I want to click the "Search" button and open a tab for each element in the LMC.
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8qgv.png)

I'm able to Log each element when I click "search", so getting the data is not the issue, the issue is being able to open each one in a new tab.

Here is the relevant code I have currently.

HomePage.html:

```
<select wicket:id="dataElement"
 class="form-control chosen-select" multiple
 data-placeholder="Select Data Elements" required>
 <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

HomePage.java

```
ChoiceRenderer<DataElement> dataElementChoiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<>(
                "displayValue");
ListMultipleChoice<DataElement> regSelect = new ListMultipleChoice<>("dataElement", this.dataElementModel,
                dataElementChoiceRenderer);

AjaxButton searchButton = new AjaxButton("search", f) {

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Collection<DataElement> convertedInput = regSelect.getConvertedInput();
        if (!convertedInput.isEmpty()) {
            setResponsePage(ResultsPage.class, params);
      }
    }
};
```

I've tried adding target="_blank" in several location and calling setResponsePage in a for loop with no success. Only the first element in the LMC is opened in a new tab.

EDIT: I figured it out
I had to use JS inside my AjaxButton

```
Url url = getRequestCycle().mapUrlFor(ResultsPage.class, params);
String js = "var w = window.open(\"" + mapUrlFor + ""\", \"_blank\");"
target.appendJavaScript(js);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out you need to use JavaScript to open multiple new browser tabs.

If you needed to open just one tab then you could have used  `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.PopupSettings` to your Button:

```
PopupSettings popupSettings = new PopupSettings("popuppagemap")
  .setHeight(500)
  .setWidth(500);
myButton.setPopupSettings(popupSettings));
```

See the examples at https://examples9x.wicket.apache.org/linkomatic/home

Comment: My apologies, I wanted new tabs instead of new windows. I have edited to post to reflect that.